# gradle bootBuildImage task failing

Tags: docker, gradle

build is success in local but the bootbuildimage task is failing with below error.

> Task :bootBuildImage
> Building image 'docker.io/library/ttk-api:1.1'

> Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' ..................................................

> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED

Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.

> Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "\.\pipe\docker_engine"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible

Comment: "Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "\.\pipe\docker_engine"; ensure the Docker daemon is running and accessible"  ==> do you have a running docker on your local machine??

Comment: Thank you. issue is with my docker instance.